# Mixed random variables

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

Given X ~ N(0,1) , Y ~ Ber(1/4)

Z =

```
 X      if Y = 0
-X      if Y = 1
```

How to approach this question if i want to prove that Z and X are dependent .

Comment: Hint: how do the distributions of $X$ and $-X$ differ?

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches

- Consider $P(Z>0 | X>0)$, which would be 0.5 if they were independent.
- For independent continuous variables $X$, $Z$, what is $P(X=Z)$?

The second approach is more powerful; it even works when $Y$ is Ber(1/2). If this is a teaching question I suspect the first one is what was intended.